# Usercontrol inside the listview, windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem binding Song title and artist to SongView usercontrol inside the listview, here's the code:
**StartPage.xaml**

```
    <ListView x:Name="PopularSongs" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Song.Title}"/>
                        <local:SongView 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            Song="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**StartPage.cs**

```
    public StartPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        vm.NewSongs.Add( new Song()
        {
            Artist = "Scorpions",
            Title = "Wind of Change",
            ImageURL = "http://images.45cat.com/scorpions-wind-of-changed-mercury.jpg",
            Length = 2.56,
            Size = 3.3
        } );

        vm.NewSongs.Add(new Song()
        {
            Artist = "Omega",
            Title = "Gyongihau Lany",
            ImageURL = "http://img11.nnm.me/b/d/c/b/7/bdcb701dbca19fde7fed545403f769fb_full.jpg",
            Length = 5.32,
            Size = 12
        });

        PopularSongs.ItemsSource = vm.NewSongs;
    }
```

*Here, vm.NewSongs is ObservableCollection of type Song*

**SongView.xaml**

```
    <UserControl
x:Class="soldo.SongView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:soldo"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="60"
d:DesignWidth="300"
x:Name="root">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ExtraLightGreyBrush}" Margin="0,3,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"> <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource OpenSansRegular}"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Song.Title, FallbackValue=Title}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"
                   FontSize="24"/>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource OpenSansBold}"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Song.Artist, FallbackValue=Artist}"
                   FontSize="15"
                   Margin="0,-5,0,0"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource OrangeBrush}"/> 
 </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**SongView.cs**

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SongProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Song",
        typeof(Song),
        typeof(SongView),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
    );

    public Song Song
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(SongProperty) as Song;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SongProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

In output are some binding errors, but i have no idea why they appear

Comment: What are the binding errors?

Comment: Also, the binding of the textblock on StartPage should be `{Binding Path=Title}`

Comment: Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Title' property not found on 'soldo.Song, soldo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Comment: Output shows 10 errors like this for 'Artist' property not found etc.

Comment: Changing to Binding Path=Title didn't help

Comment: Can you show the code of your `Song` object? I suspect you used fields instead of properties, this is not supported on Windows Phone

Comment: public class Song
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Artist;
        public string ImageURL;
        public double Length;
        public bool   IsPlaying;
        public double Size; // Size in MB
    }

Comment: Thanks for help:)

Comment: Oh yeah, properties work so good, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone, databinding doesn't work with fields. Make sure you're binding only on properties.